# How can I slow down my for loop so I can see the colors?

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to delay my loop so that it will show the background colors I put in. Right now, it is just too fast.

The objective is to let the colors flash to create a disco effect. I used `Thread.Sleep` but that just doesn't work.

Here's my current attempt:

```
private void Disco(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
           for (int n =0; n<=10;n++)
           {
               Background = Brushes.Coral;
               Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
               Background = Brushes.DarkRed;
               Background = Brushes.Red;
               Background = Brushes.Blue;
               Background = Brushes.Aquamarine;
           }
       }
```

Comment: You are not supposed to use a for loop to do animations like this. What UI framework are you using? WPF?

Comment: Using a Timer class can help with that, it will also require you to change your loop flow.

Comment: Try to add Thread.Sleep(5000); below Background = .. lines. If i'd be you i'd create new one method to change background.

Comment: The most easier way is using `await Task.Delay(500);` and mark you method with `async`.

Comment: Though asynchronous programming will work, asynchronous programming is not for scenarios where you need tight time bounds on exactly when an update happens, as is the case with animations. Can you say more about what sort of timeframe you are looking at for each change, and what your budget is for error?  There are special-purpose controls for animations and you probably should be using them.

Comment: FYI if you are using Thread.Sleep in production code for anything other than yielding a thread, you are almost always doing something very wrong. Threads are meant to be doing work, not sleeping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `async` method, which @Jeroen van Langen suggested in the comments.

Using `await Task.Delay(time)` in between `Background` changes will delay the changes by a given `time`.

```
private async void Disco(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Background = Brushes.Coral;
    await Task.Delay(500); // 500 is just an example. You can use any number in milliseconds.
    Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
    await Task.Delay(500);
    Background = Brushes.DarkRed;
    await Task.Delay(500);
    Background = Brushes.Red;
    await Task.Delay(500);
    Background = Brushes.Blue;
    await Task.Delay(500);
    Background = Brushes.Aquamarine;
    await Task.Delay(500);
    //Set the background back to its original color here.
}
```

If you need your form to continue to "disco" until, for example, a button is pressed again, you can wrap it in a `while` loop that'll continue until a `Button` is pressed, or a `ToggleButton` is checked.

If you go this route, I suggest you read up on the [asynchronous programming documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). It's extremely helpful.

Answer (score -2):

This code works for mi, and changes the Back color every 5 seconds:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            /// 
            /// a list of colors to control the sequence
            ///
```

`Color[] colorsList = { Color.Coral, Color.AliceBlue, Color.DarkRed, Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Aquamarine };

        /// <summary>
        /// Timer to control the execution time of the color change
        /// </summary>
        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load or Main of class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = colorsList[0];
            myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            myTimer.Interval = 5000;
            myTimer.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// method that changes the color, executed by the timer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {            
            for (int i = 0; i < colorsList.Length; i++)
            {
                if (this.BackColor == colorsList[i])
                {
                    if (i < colorsList.Length - 1)
                    {
                        this.BackColor = colorsList[i + 1];
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //return to the first color
                        this.BackColor = colorsList[0];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: This would always set the background to aquamarine.

Comment: You have to create a method for each color

Comment: Assuming the timers are all roughly synchronized then you will have the same problem (or worse). This isn't a solution, I think you might want to rethink the approach.

Comment: I do not understand, your problem was that in a loop the colors change very quickly, in this way you will be able to control the time.
You can create a variable that contains the time value you want.

Comment: In your example you have set a timer interval of 5000 for each Timer. At the speed that this code would execute, all of your timer events would more or less be called at about the same time. Not only that but why would you create a method for each individual colour you want, why not just iterate a list or array within a single method?

Comment: the interval is just an example can be changed, I created a code that worked for me, you have to control when the tamer is executed (Start, Strop)

Comment: This is not at all the right way to solve this problem. If you're going to use a timer, use *one* timer, not a timer per color! And certainly do not make one method per color.

Comment: @EricLippert 
You're right, but it's just an example you have to create a list to control all this, and create a timer that receives the color parameter.

Comment: Example code quickly becomes production code; example code should be best practices code.  Show beginners best practices!

Comment: Do you try this code? I have edited the code !!! Sorry for the format is not as it should.